# Hasse principle and what it precisely mean

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, for $f\in[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ a non-zero homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ we say that $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in k^n$ is a solution if $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$. Such a solution is called non-trivial if $a_i \neq 0$ for at least one $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Suppose now that $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. We say that $f$ satisfies *Hasse Principle* if 
\begin{align}
f \text{ has a non-trivial solution in } \mathbb{Q}^n \Longleftrightarrow 
f \text{ has a non-trivial } \mathbb{Q}_p \text{ solutions for all } p=2,3,5,\ldots, \infty.
\end{align}
Here $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of $p$-adic numbers (which is a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ by the way).

I understand what is meant by " **$\mathbb{Q}^n$ solutions**". But I don`t precisely understand what is meant by " **$\mathbb{Q_p}$ solutions**". My guess is the following:
the $n$-tuple $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)\in \mathbb{Q_p}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}_p$ solution if $f(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)=0$ as defined above. Is this true?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Since $\mathbb{Q}$ embedds into $\mathbb{Q}_p$, you get the same for their polynomial rings. Hence you can consider $f$ as a polynomial over the $p$-adics and look for solutions there (just don't forget to write $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ as you want $n$-tuples).